# How to get caller information using lambda-proxy and IAM authorizer

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I have a cognito user pool used in conjunction with a cognito identity pool to provide fine-grained access controls to endpoints in my API gateway, which all use the IAM authorizer. Some of my endpoints need to know the identity of the caller. I've seen various pieces of documentation showing how to get at the claims using lambda integration (not lambda proxy), and how to get at the claims if you're using a cognito user pool authorizer directly. The configuration overhead of lambda integration turns me away from that, and a user pool authorizer doesn't provide the fine-grained access control I get from using groups and cognito identity to have users assume an IAM role with privileges to the correct API gateway endpoints.

What am I missing here? How do I get information about the calling user with a user-pool+identity+IAM-authorizer combination? My event objects looks like this (liberally removed any potentially dangerous information, but you can see what fields I have available):

```
{
    "resource": "/{accountName}/user/{email}",
    "path": "/testAccount/user/ommitted",
    "httpMethod": "GET",
    "headers": {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, sdch, br",
        "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.8",
        "CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto": "https",
        "CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer": "true",
        "CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer": "false",
        "CloudFront-Is-SmartTV-Viewer": "false",
        "CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer": "false",
        "CloudFront-Viewer-Country": "US",
        "Host": "ommitted",
        "origin": "http://127.0.0.1:4200",
        "Referer": "http://127.0.0.1:4200/",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/58.0.3029.96 Chrome/58.0.3029.96 Safari/537.36",
        "Via": "ommitted",
        "X-Amz-Cf-Id": "ommitted",
        "X-AMZ-Date": "20170524T135448Z",
        "x-amz-security-token": "ommitted",
        "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "ommitted",
        "X-Forwarded-For": "ommitted",
        "X-Forwarded-Port": "443",
        "X-Forwarded-Proto": "https"
    },
    "queryStringParameters": null,
    "pathParameters": {
        "accountName": "testAccount",
        "email": "ommitted"
    },
    "stageVariables": null,
    "requestContext": {
        "path": "/dev/testAccount/user/ommitted",
        "accountId": "ommitted",
        "resourceId": "ommitted",
        "stage": "dev",
        "requestId": "8df123f6-4088-11e7-b078-8775511f5c09",
        "identity": {
            "cognitoIdentityPoolId": "us-east-2:ommitted",
            "accountId": "ommitted",
            "cognitoIdentityId": "us-east-2:ommitted",
            "caller": "ommitted:CognitoIdentityCredentials",
            "apiKey": "",
            "sourceIp": "ommitted",
            "accessKey": "ommitted",
            "cognitoAuthenticationType": "authenticated",
            "cognitoAuthenticationProvider": "cognito-idp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/ommitted,cognito-idp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/ommitted:CognitoSignIn:ommitted",
            "userArn": "arn:aws:sts::ommitted:assumed-role/Cognito_idp_identitypoolAuth_Role/CognitoIdentityCredentials",
            "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/58.0.3029.96 Chrome/58.0.3029.96 Safari/537.36",
            "user": "ommitted:CognitoIdentityCredentials"
        },
        "resourcePath": "/{accountName}/user/{email}",
        "httpMethod": "GET",
        "apiId": "{
        "resource": "/{accountName}/user/{email}",
        "path": "/testAccount/user/ommitted",
        "httpMethod": "GET",
        "headers": {
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, sdch, br",
            "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.8",
            "CloudFront-Forwarded-Proto": "https",
            "CloudFront-Is-Desktop-Viewer": "true",
            "CloudFront-Is-Mobile-Viewer": "false",
            "CloudFront-Is-SmartTV-Viewer": "false",
            "CloudFront-Is-Tablet-Viewer": "false",
            "CloudFront-Viewer-Country": "US",
            "Host": "ommitted",
            "origin": "http://127.0.0.1:4200",
            "Referer": "http://127.0.0.1:4200/",
            "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/58.0.3029.96 Chrome/58.0.3029.96 Safari/537.36",
            "Via": "ommitted",
            "X-Amz-Cf-Id": "ommitted",
            "X-AMZ-Date": "20170524T135448Z",
            "x-amz-security-token": "ommitted",
            "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "ommitted",
            "X-Forwarded-For": "ommitted",
            "X-Forwarded-Port": "443",
            "X-Forwarded-Proto": "https"
        },
        "queryStringParameters": null,
        "pathParameters": {
            "accountName": "testAccount",
            "email": "ommitted"
        },
        "stageVariables": null,
        "requestContext": {
            "path": "/dev/testAccount/user/ommitted",
            "accountId": "ommitted",
            "resourceId": "ommitted",
            "stage": "dev",
            "requestId": "8df123f6-4088-11e7-b078-8775511f5c09",
            "identity": {
                "cognitoIdentityPoolId": "us-east-2:ommitted",
                "accountId": "ommitted",
                "cognitoIdentityId": "us-east-2:ommitted",
                "caller": "ommitted:CognitoIdentityCredentials",
                "apiKey": "",
                "sourceIp": "ommitted",
                "accessKey": "ommitted",
                "cognitoAuthenticationType": "authenticated",
                "cognitoAuthenticationProvider": "cognito-idp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/ommitted,cognito-idp.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/ommitted:CognitoSignIn:ommitted",
                "userArn": "arn:aws:sts::ommitted:assumed-role/Cognito_idp_identitypoolAuth_Role/CognitoIdentityCredentials",
                "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/58.0.3029.96 Chrome/58.0.3029.96 Safari/537.36",
                "user": "ommitted:CognitoIdentityCredentials"
            },
            "resourcePath": "/{accountName}/user/{email}",
            "httpMethod": "GET",
            "apiId": "ommitted"
        },
        "body": null,
        "isBase64Encoded": false
    }
    "
},
"body": null,
"isBase64Encoded": false
}
```

Comment: Check out the context object - I believe it'll be in there - If the user info isn't and the Identity Token is there you can use the JWT library to decode it and it'll have all the claims inside.

Comment: I checked the context object as well, though I didn't include it in this question.  It didn't have any user information in it or tokens.  For now I've worked around this by requiring that the access token be sent in a custom header, I can then use the token to get user info from cognito.  This of course won't work for federated identifies from other auth sources, but I'll cross that bridge when I come to it.

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find a solution?

Comment: I moved away from using the federated identities system.  Using the I AM authorizer is too restrictive, I ended up using a custom authorizer that let's me dictate which data gets passed through to the lambdas.